# Passing value angular to the node

Tags: angularjs, node.js

I'm trying to pass the form values but I'm not getting it, I've tried it in several ways.
Apparently Node.js is not recognizing the parameters passed to the url, I have no idea what it might be.

```
//AngularController
$scope.adicionarUsuario = function () {

    $http.post("/usuario/salvar",{params:{"usuario":$scope.usuarioform}})
    .success(function (data) {
        delete $scope.usuarioform;
        alert(data);
        $scope.salvo = true;
        $scope.cadastraUsuario.$setPristine();
    }).error(function (data) {
        $scope.erro = true;
        $scope.message = "Aconteceu um problema: " + data;
    });
};

//Node Server
app.post("/usuario/salvar",function (req, res){
usuario = req.params.usuario;
if(usuario.nome == null){
    console.error("Ocorreu algum problema");
    res.status(500).send('Acontenceu algum problema!');
}else{
    MongoClient.connect(url, function (err, db) {
      if (err){
        console.error(err.stack);
        res.status(500).send('Acontenceu algum problema!');
      }else {
        var collection = db.collection('usuarios');

        //Salvar Usuario
        var salva_usu = {nome: usuario.nome, email: usuario.email, senha: usuario.senha};

        collection.insert(salva_usu, function (err, result) {
          if (err){
            console.error("Ocorreu algum problema");
            res.status(500).send('Acontenceu algum problema!');
          }else res.status(200).send("Salvo!");
        });

        //Fecha a conexão
        db.close();
      }
    });
}
```

})

Answer (score 0):

It's more common to send parameters using `data` in a `POST`, especially yours is an object rather than strings.

You can try modifying your code to use `data`, or send the 3 strings you need in 3 different `params`.

Personally I prefer the first way because your data contains a password, which doesn't look nice if it is appended in the request URL.

Answer (score 0):

The request's data is available under the `data` attribute.

Also, it's most likely just going to be a JSON literal -- that is, a JS `String`. Parse it with `JSON.parse()`!

Simply replace:

```
app.post("/usuario/salvar",function (req, res) {
    usuario = req.params.usuario;
    // ...
```

By:

```
app.post("/usuario/salvar",function (req, res) {
    usuario = JSON.parse(req.data).params.usuario;
```